# heroku run bash gives error: ! ! ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000

Tags: windows-firewall, heroku

I'm trying to use `heroku run bash` on windows 10, but get the following error:

```
>heroku run bash
Running bash on ⬢ map-test-portal... !
 !    ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000
```

I have tried allowing the port 5000 through the firewall and restarting Command Prompt as administrator.

Is there anything else I am missing to get a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Commands can be run from the [heroku dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1137).

[image]

[image]